# Probability that at least one CD is placed in its proper case

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

> Suppose that three compact discs are removed from their cases, and
>   that after they have been played, they are put back into the three
>   empty cases in a random manner. Determine the probability that at
>   least one of the CD’s will be put back into the proper cases.

I was thinking that the sample space would be $3!$, and that $A_i$ would be the number of possibilities with correct placement for disk $i$ would be from $1-3$. So it would be $Pr(A_i)=\frac{A_i}{3!}$. I'm not sure how I would find $A_i$ because it would also be dependent on if the disk was placed back first, second, or third.

Comment: As a practical matter I can assure you that the probability is $0$.  It simply never, ever happens.  On a more abstract note, just list all the permutations and count the good ones.  There are only six.  If you want a more general technique, look up [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

Comment: The answer key says: "This is a case of the matching problem with $n = 3$. We are asked to find $p_3$. In the text, this equals $p_3 = 1 − \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{2}{3}$

Comment: Well, I don't have your book in hand so I don't know what they are calling the "matching problem".  But, come on.  There are only six permutations!  $123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321$.  Of these, four have at least one matching entry so the answer is $\frac 46 = \frac 23$.

Comment: It seems to me that if the CDs are put in the cases in a truly random manner then there is some chance that all three will be put in the same case, or that two will go in one case, one in another, the third case beiong left empty. That's probably not the intended interpretation, but I think it's a valid one – the author should have taken more care in writing the problem.

Comment: @lulu well the matching problem appears in most elementary probability books. It usually contains examples like exact same umbrellas returning to their original owners, or this one. The author usually derives that the probability that exactly $m$ CD's go into their proper cases is $1\over m!$ and then uses the inclusion-exclusion principle to find the probability of at least one happenning.

Answer (score 1):

As @lulu stated in the comments, since there are only six cases, the simplest way to do this problem is to list the possibilities and eliminate those that have no CD in its proper case.

$123$

$132$

$213$

$\color{red}{231}$

$\color{red}{312}$

$321$

Since $4$ of the $6$ cases have at least one matching CD, the desired probability is $2/3$.  Those shown in red are called [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), permutations in no object is left in its proper place.

You want to calculate this by finding $p(A_i)$, where $A_i$ is the event that the $i$th CD is placed in the $i$th case.  Then we need to find 
$$p(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3) = p(A_1) + p(A_2) + p(A_3) - p(A_1 \cap A_2) - p(A_1 \cap A_3) - p(A_2 \cap A_3) + p(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)$$
If disk $i$ is left in its proper case, then there are $2!$ ways of arranging the remaining disk, so 
$$p(A_1) = p(A_2) = p(A_3) = \frac{2!}{3!} = \frac{1}{3}$$
If disks $i$ and $j$, with $i \neq j$, are left in their proper cases, then there is one way of arranging the remaining disks, so 
$$p(A_1 \cap A_2) = p(A_1 \cap A_3) = p(A_2 \cap A_3) = \frac{1}{3!} = \frac{1}{6}$$
Finally, there is only one way to place all three of the compact disks in their proper place.  Hence, 
$$p(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) = \frac{1}{6}$$
Hence, the probability that at least one disk is in its proper place is 
\begin{align*}
p(A \cup B \cup C) & = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6}\\
& = 3 \cdot \frac{1}{3} - 3 \cdot \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6}\\
& = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6}\\
& = \frac{2}{3}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

I think before this exercise in your book, you must have encountered something like this:
Suppose you have $n$ CDs. After rearranging, what is the probability that at least $1$ of them ends up in its proper case?
Then, the author would go on something like this:
Let $A_k$ be the event that the $k$th CD goes into the correct case. 
Let $(i_1,i_2 ... i_n)$ be a random permutation of the CDs such that the $k$th case gets the $i_k$th CD.
Consider the $m$ events $A_{x_1},A_{x_2}...A_{x_m}$ where $m \le n$.These all events will happen together only if $i_{x_1} = x_1, i_{x_2} = x_2, ... i_{x_m} = x_m$ all happen. Other $n-m$ CDs can go into any cases (so we can permute them anyhow), but these must go into their proper cases. We get:
$$P\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^mA_{x_j}\right) = \frac{(n-m)!}{n!}$$But, you can choose the events in $\binom{n}{m}$ ways. Each choice will have the same probability, so the probability that at least $m$ of them are correctly kept becomes:
$$\sum_{1\le x_1<x_2...<x_m \le n}P\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^mA_{x_j}\right) =\binom{n}{m}\frac{(n-m)!}{n!} = \frac{n!(n-m)!}{m!n!(n-m)!} = \frac 1{m!}$$
Finally, the probability that at least one of them is correctly kept is:
$$P\left(\bigcup_{l=1}^n A_l\right) = \sum_{l=1}^n(-1)^{l+1}\frac{1}{l!}$$by the [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) principle (must have already been covered in the book).
For the case $n=3$, the probability is:
$$\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!} = \frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6} = \color{green}{\frac 23}$$